# Mapping MultiList using Glass Mapper

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I am using Glass Mapper : 4.0.1.8 to map multilist to the `IEnumerable`in Sitecore 8. It does returns the number of count in the `IEnumerable` correctly but the fields inside that are all mapped to null. Following is the code that I am using:

```
public void GetPromotedNews()
{
   var NewsListingPage = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(new ID(ItemIDS.NewsListingCorporate));
   var NewsListingPageItem = NewsListingPage.GlassCast<NewsListingPage>();
      
   foreach (var newslistingcategory in NewsListingPageItem.NewsCategory) //This is returning two results which are correct 
   {
      var item = newslistingcategory.CategoryName; //this is always returning null ?
   }     
}

public class NewsListingPage
{
   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Page title")]
   public string PageTitle { get; set; }

   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Page description")]
   public string PageDescription {get; set;}

   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "News category", Setting = SitecoreFieldSettings.InferType)]
   public virtual IEnumerable<ContentCategory> NewsCategory { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = DCP.Resources.TemplateIDS.CategoryTemplateID, AutoMap = true)]
public class ContentCategory : SCItem
{
   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Category name")]
   public string CategoryName { get; set; }
   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Category icon")]
   public Image CategoryICON { get; set; }

   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "text")]
   public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Updating your content category model to have virtual properties

```
[SitecoreType(TemplateId = DCP.Resources.TemplateIDS.CategoryTemplateID, AutoMap = true)]
public class ContentCategory : SCItem
{
   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Category name")]
   public virtual string CategoryName { get; set; }
   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Category icon")]
   public virtual Image CategoryICON { get; set; }

   [SitecoreField(FieldName = "text")]
   public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Making them virtual](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31912438/4320665) should do the trick.

An alternate reason you run into null using GlassMapper is it cannot resolve the type you are trying to map to.  For example, if I set my type to `string` but it was really a `List<string>`.   I would also recommend TDS.  You can source control TDS items and auto generate your classes.

Comment: Sorry I will do, I am new to this all

Answer (score 0):

Two possible causes are when I ran into this issue.

1. Template is not published correctly.
2. I added  following attribute on my field.

   ```
   [SitecoreField(Setting = Glass.Mapper.Sc.Configuration.SitecoreFieldSettings.DontLoadLazily)]
   ```